# Why am I getting null when I divide two BigDecimal variables in Jaspersoft Studio?

Tags: java, jasper-reports, bigdecimal

I have a few variables set up. The first two set the integer value of one field to BigDecimal:

```
$V{Active Unit}.valueOf( $F{Price Qty} ) 
$V{Reg Unit}.valueOf( $F{Reg Retail Unit} )
```

The next two variables I create then divide a field by that variable. (I am at this point finding unit price 2 for $1.00 show as .50 this way).  These are returning NULL!

```
$F{Price}.divide($V{Current Unit Price})
$F{Reg Retail}.divide($V{Regular Unit Price})
```

I then subtract the two newly created variables from each other (This is to find out my markdown for discounted items .75 - .50 is a .25 markdown per item).  This is also returning NULL!

```
$F{Reg Retail}.divide($V{Regular Unit Price})
```

Any ideas what I am doing wrong?  I know very little java, I am using this through Jaspersoft Studio.  Based on what I have read, I believe I have constrcuted this correctly.  Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: What did you assign to Price, Reg Retail, Current Unit Price, and Regular Unit Price?

Comment: Don't you have to do something like this: `.valueOf($F{Price Qty}.doubleValue())`?

Comment: I tried this 
$V{Active Unit}.valueOf( $F{Price Qty}.BigDecimal())
but I get the following error:  
The method BigDecimal() is undefined for the type Integer.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you have to do something like this: `.valueOf($F{Price Qty}.doubleValue())`.  Another thing you might want to do is check for NULL like this: `($F{myField} != null) ? $F{myField}.doSomething() : null`. This way, if the value is not set, your code will know how to handle the value of the field is null.

**UPDATE**

If the desired value is `BigDecimal` but the value is some other numeric type (i.e. *Integer*), you would have to convert the value to `BigDecimal` before invoking the `divide()` method:

```
new BigDecimal($F{var1}).divide(new BigDecimal($F{var2}))
```

Something like the above should work.

Comment: I tried the above, however I am getting the following error now

The method BigDecimal is undefined for the type Integer.

I have to use BigDecimal since I am calculating currency, however I also tried doubleValue and got the same error message for it as well.

Comment: @AaronMartin, the methods have to be compatible with the data type you defined.  If the value you are obtaining is an Integer, you must convert it to `BigDecimal` first (if that is what you need).  To do this, you can use the `BigDecimal(int)` constructor. Once you have the `BigDecimal` instance, you can use it to call the `BigDecimal.divide(BigDecimal)` method.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar situation. My variable "SALDO", that subtracted "TOTAL_SAIDA" from "TOTAL_ENTRADA", showed up right in most of cases, but some day we found a set of report parameters that made the variable show null!

This is how the variables were declared:

```
<variable name="TOTAL_ENTRADA" class="java.math.BigDecimal" calculation="Sum">
    <variableExpression><![CDATA[$F{es_case}.equals("E") ? $F{valor_total_nota_fiscal} : new BigDecimal(0.0)]]></variableExpression>
</variable>
<variable name="TOTAL_SAIDA" class="java.math.BigDecimal" calculation="Sum">
    <variableExpression><![CDATA[$F{es_case}.equals("S") ? $F{valor_total_nota_fiscal} : new BigDecimal(0.0)]]></variableExpression>
</variable>
<variable name="SALDO" class="java.math.BigDecimal" resetType="Column">
    <variableExpression><![CDATA[$V{TOTAL_ENTRADA}.subtract($V{TOTAL_SAIDA})]]></variableExpression>
</variable>
```

That variable was then put in a text field placed right after a table filled with data from a report query.

To figure out the situation I had to understand the "resetType" configuration, as the iReport Ultimate Guide reads:

> This specifies when a variable value has to be reset to the initial value (or to null if no initial value expression has been provided) [...]

And the reset type "Column" means:

> The variable is initialized again in each new column (or in each page if the report is composed of only one column).

After reading that, I noticed that the text field containg "SALDO" was the first thing to appear on the page (in the specific mentioned case). The value of "SALDO" was reset to null and, since there was no more results from the report query, it hasn't changed. If the table before the text field had just one line appearing on the page, "SALDO" would show up correctly.

Using iReport I changed this config to "Report", which made the variable to initialize only once at the beginning of report creation. The correct value of "SALDO" popped in the text field.